# InstallShield outputting incorrect reference binary

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, installshield

I have an application which works fine when built in `Visual Studio`. When this application is built by the `Visual Studio 2012` standard `InstallShield` project, it doesn't.

The application uses `System.Threading.Tasks` from `NuGet`. When the application is built using `Visual Studio`, it output the correct version. When it is built using the `InstallShield` installer, a *different* version of `System.Threading.Tasks` is deployed. This causes the application to crash.

My question is, why is a different version of `System.Threading.Tasks` being emitted as the primary output to the installer project?

I hope I have explained this well enough. Please see the attached screen shots for more information.

**Reference Properties**

[image: Reference Properties]

**Debug Output**

[image: Debug Output]

**Installer Output**

[image: Installer Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I added the `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` directly from the `NuGet` folder into the installer output. This seems to overwrite the `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` the installer was getting - which is possibly what Visual Studio is doing behind the scenes when creating the Debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help anyone.. but I had the same issue with the Telerik.Windows.Data assembly.

Even though I had the version I want packaged and referenced inside my project whenever I built the installer it for some reason kept picking up an older version from somewhere

How I ended up fixing it was doing a full search of my C:\ drive for the assembly and deleting everything besides the particular one i want (There were lots of random telerik.windows.data scattered all over the place) .. it seemed to work for I guess it was picking it up from somewhere else